# Cannot render images on GeoServer SLD?

Tags: geoserver, sld

I updated from Geoserver 2.1.3 to 2.8.0 and I copied my SLD styles.

I had all the images in a folder name "symbols" and my SLD was like

```
<PointSymbolizer>
  <Graphic>           
    <ExternalGraphic>             
      <OnlineResource          xlink:type="simple"xlink:href="symbols/aerodrome.p.16.png" />
       <!-- href has a "symbols/" prefix to access the folder -->
      <Format>image/png</Format>           
    </ExternalGraphic>           
    <Size>32</Size>
  </Graphic>       
</PointSymbolizer>
```

I also copied the "sympbols" folder to the `data_dir\styles` folder.

Images are now in `data_dir\styles\symbols`

Used to work in 2.1.3, but not in 2.8.0, I cannot see the images in the preview.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What errors do you get? Check the logs (geoserver.log in the data directory)